# MySQLi does not return error code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my MySQL database I have a table "table1" with unique constraint set on column "name" - I want to prevent duplicate names.

If there's already name 'John' in table this code:

```
$db=new mysqli(...);

$sql="INSERT INTO table1 SET id=10,name='John'";

if(!$db->query($sql))
{
  if($db->errno==1062)
  {
    throw new InsertNonUniqueException(...);
  }
  else
  {
    throw new InsertException(...);
  }
}
```

should throw InsertNonUniqueException() (my own exception). Instead, it throws InsertException().

Execution of query returns false and execution enters the if() loop. Also $db->row_affected is -1 but problem is that $db->errno is always O (it should be 1062)!!! So I can't detect that my insert error was caused by violating unique key constraint on name column!

I don't know why mysqli does not return 1062 code when unique key constraint violation occurs!

Comment: Are you sure you have an unique index on your column?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, because if I execute the same sql in SQL command line it returns "Error code 1062, SQL state 23000: Duplicate entry 'John' for key..."

Comment: Debug it with `if($db->errno)` Does it goes to the same if branch?

Comment: echo $db->errno and see what is says.

Comment: I see in my debugger that $db->errno=0 and $db->error is empty

Comment: Try to change it to `if($db->error)`

Comment: Is it possible that there is a connection error? Check `$db->connect_error`.

Comment: No there's no problem with connection, it works fine, all sql statements are executed just fine.

Comment: Have you considered switching to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)? mysql & mysqli extensions are things of the past...

Comment: You can try adding `var_dump($db);` before `if($db->errno==1062)` in order to see some properties of the connection, that may help you to debug further the issue.

Comment: Your sql code works fine here - mysql 5.5.16. I assume that the 'throw InsertNonUniqueException' is a typing error as it should be: 'throw  new insertNonUniqueException(...'.

Comment: try `INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES (10, 'John')`

Comment: Could you include `table1` declared structure in your question body?

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave a comment, thus going to ask you here.

Please provide the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;`

I can't reproduce your problem using your code and next table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
`name` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I *the only one* around here that thinks **you have an error** in your SQL syntax?.. There is no room for `SET` in `INSERT INTO`, because you can only use `SET` in `UPDATE` statements (assuming you habe MySQL in version 5.5 or below).

`INSERT INTO` syntax is like the following (as [described in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)):

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Try it like this:

```
<?php
$sql="INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES ('10', 'John')";
...
```

Comment: You can use `SET` in `INSERT INTO` with mysql : [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

Comment: @Meeuuuhhhh OK, in MySQL 5.6 and above. In 5.5 an below it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

**step 1**

make sure that the table has a unique key

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table1
```

expected result

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` INT(11) default NULL,
    `name` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

if there is `UNIQUE KEY name (name)` we have a unique key

**step 2**

try to change your code

```
$db  = new mysqli(...);

// first insert
if( !$db->query("INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES (10, 'John')") ) {
  throw new Exception($db->error);
}

// second insert (for me raise:  Duplicate entry 'John' for key 'name')
if( !$db->query("INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES (11, 'John')") ) {
  throw new Exception($db->error);
}
```

Please, try these two steps

*Side note: if you have name and id as duplicates, only the first duplicate encountered will be returned in the message.*

Answer (score 0):

The only issue i have with your code is that:

having setup your table and columns.

I setup a unique index on the table. I did .. stuff on a two column table that ensure it works.

You missed the **'new'**
 keyword when you 'throw exceptions'.
this is the only error with your posted code that i could find.

i.e: throw new Exception('Division by zero.'); // example taken from PHP manual.